# Wordpress and WebRTC?

Tags: plugins, audio, customization

I'm pretty new to WordPress and I was wondering about [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) integration : user permissions, page integration...
I'm especially interested in chat communications (writing and audio, video is not my first concern).
[At the moment the only available plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/webrtc) are about video communications and use an external solution (service).

Does someone have already addressed this topic and would share some hint?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some researches I came across two plugins using WebRTC :

- [Collaboration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/collaboration/), which is a simple integration of TogetherJS
- [wpRTC](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wprtc-real-time-video-for-wp/) which is not enough mature yet but look promising !